# R ggvis plot: using tooltip half my scatter points disappear when I hover

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, ggvis

I'm creating a ggvis scatterplot using shiny.  I'm having issues with the tooltip function.  When I hover over the scatter plot, half my points on the scatterplot disappears.  I can then see the tooltip information for the remaining half.

Anyone have the same issues?  To reproduce the error, you can download the code and source files from:

https://github.com/er3kim78/Shiny

```
Server File:
library(ggvis)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/EK/Desktop/Files/R Scripts/Shiny VRC")


# read the data
vrc<- read.csv("Data File Example.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")
str(vrc)
vrc$Impr<-as.numeric(vrc$Impr)
str(vrc)

shinyServer(

function(input, output) {

main_plot <- reactive({ 
xvar<-switch(input$xvar, 
"Clicks" = vrc$Clicks,
"Cost" = vrc$Cost,
"Impr" = vrc$Impr)
yvar<-switch(input$yvar, 
"Clicks" = vrc$Clicks,
"Cost" = vrc$Cost,
"Impr" = vrc$Impr)

vrc%>%
ggvis(~xvar, ~yvar, opacity:=0.4, key:=~Keyword) %>%
layer_points() %>%
#    layer_text(text:=as.character(vrc$Account)) %>%  
add_tooltip(function(vrc){paste0("Keyword: ", vrc$Keyword,"<br>xvar: ",vrc$xvar, 
"<br>yvar:", vrc$yvar)},"hover")
#   plot(xvar, yvar)
})
main_plot %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
})
```

UI file: 
    library(ggvis)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Paid Search Report"),
fluidRow(
column(3,
wellPanel(
h2("Metrics"),
selectInput("xvar", "X-Axis Variable", axis_vars, selected = "Clicks"),
selectInput("yvar", "Y-Axis Variable", axis_vars, selected = "Cost")
)),
column(9,
ggvisOutput("plot1")
)
)))
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal self-contained example and post it to the ggvis mailing list?

Comment: @hadley I posted the question on https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/234

the reproducible code & source file is on my github
https://github.com/er3kim78/Shiny

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same problem but only a few points were disappearing, also the tooltip hover was going haywire!. Changing the rendering from svg to canvas fixed the issue for me. 
Can be done using `set_options(renderer = "canvas")` for the ggvis plot.